# Adding Binary Overflow Character

Tags: amsmath, mathtools

How would I show a 1 carry over an empty space?

Such as this;

[image]

Currently I have this as code;

```
\usepackage{array,mathtools}
\newcommand*{\carry}[1][1]{\overset{#1}}
\newcolumntype{B}[1]{r*{#1}{@{\,}r}}

\[
\begin{array}{B3}
    \carry 0 \carry 1 \carry 11 \\
      {} + 0101 \\ \hline
           1100 \\
\end{array}
\]
```

When I use `\carry \carry`, I get an error.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution employs an `array` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,xcolor}
\newcommand\cy{\scriptstyle\textcolor{blue}{1}} % short for "\carry"

\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\begin{array}{*{6}{c}}
  & \cy & \cy &     & \cy &   \\[-0.8ex]
  &     &   1 &   1 &   0 & 1 \\
+ &     &   0 &   1 &   0 & 1 \\ 
\hline
  &   1 &   0 &   0 &   1 & 0 
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```